# How to send message from BroadcastReceiver to activity or fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I have a receiver, it does call details saving task like storing incoming call, outgoing call etc.. all these details goes to sqlite DB. If my activity is not running, then its fine.

Sometime, when my activity is running, i get some incoming call. the receiver runs & stores data to DB. UI wont get refreshed because it never knows about change in DB.

Here i need to manually tell from receiver that, if activity is running refresh screen. How to implement this process in android.

I'm slightly confused in this part

Answer (score 4):

You can use a LocalBroadcastManager to send a local broadcast to your Activity (more efficient and more secure than using a global broadcast):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(action);
LocalBroadcastManager mgr = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
mgr.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Your Activity would have to register a BroadcastReceiver in onStart and unregister it in onStop:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;

mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do your thing
    }       
};

LocalBroadcastManager mgr = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
mgr.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(action));
```

in onStop:

```
mgr.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver)
```

Now that's the official Android way to do it. I most certainly prefer to use an event/message bus like Otto or EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). You can use those to broadcast messages/events across different components in your app. The advantage is you don't need access to a Context (like you do when using Broadcasts), it's faster and it forces the developer to object oriented programming (since the events are always objects). Once you start using an event bus you'll never look back to local broadcasts and you'll replace many of the sometimes messy observer / listener patterns used across your app.

Comment: Hi, +1 for the help, thanks. Your answer worked well. Thank you so much. i would like to know, if you have any answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449858/how-long-android-take-to-update-call-details-to-call-log

Comment: Well since you seem to prefer the inferior answer (maybe because it was faster?) I'll pass on your next question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a BroadcastReceiver inside an activity. Register it in onResume() and unregister it in onPause(). Whenever your other receiver receives a broadcast, send a broadcast to this receiver too. If the activity is running(i.e. on front), the broadcast will be received. Do whatever you want in its onReceive().

Example:

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Do stuff
        }
    };
```

Also override methods:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(br);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("intent_filter"));//Use any string for IntentFilter you like
}
```

You can update fragments from activiy by creating methods inside fragment and access them from Fragment object inside activity.

Comment: could you please tell me any sample code. any example is welcome. Thanks for hint. I'm using list fragment & it needs to be notified

Comment: Here, i dont need to perform any operation from my receiver right?, i just need to add the code guided by you in my activity and try thats all right?

Comment: @Naruto Ofcourse u need to perform action in receiver. As I said:  Whenever your other receiver receives a broadcast, send a broadcast to this receiver too. If the activity is running(i.e. on front), the broadcast will be received. Do whatever you want in its onReceive().

Comment: Is this the way to send `Intent intent = new Intent(action);
LocalBroadcastManager mgr = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
mgr.sendBroadcast(intent);`. Actually i have added filters for actual receiver in manifest file, but in receiver do i need to add them again like i pasted in the comment code?. i mean here action means what?

Comment: @Naruto The broadcast receiver is identified by its IntentFilter. To send an Intent to this broadcast, send like: Intent in=new Intent("intent_filter");in.putExtra(//put any extras u want);context.sendBroadcast(in);

Comment: Ok, got it, its working. Thanks but one thing, is its better to register receiver once the activity is started & we can un-register in onDestry right?. What is the benifit to do in onReceive & onPause, can you tell me the reason please.

Comment: @Naruto If you unregister in onPause, the receiver will not be called when the activity goes in background. If you unregister in onDestroy, the receiver will be called when the activity goes in background but not destroyed.

Comment: Ok, in my case, i need to catch the call events. So whenever i get call, my activity goes to Background, here on pause method calls & it will be unregistered. once the view is focused it will be registered but by that time if my DB is updated, again i wont get the update right?

Comment: @Naruto Yes, it won't update if unregistered in onPause. For your case, register in onCreate and unregister in onDestroy. But I guess views cannot be updated in backround. So, try updating views in onResume if the app was in background.

Comment: Ok, but i assume view will be in memory for few mins, later on garbage collector destroy the view. in that case my activity may not get refreshed right or will it crash??

Comment: @Naruto Give it a try :D

Comment: Nope it didn't, sorry for troubling you, Thanks for your help. both answers are right. ill give you right mark. Thanks

Comment: Can you help me if you have any idea for this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449858/how-long-android-take-to-update-call-details-to-call-log