# button.performclick() java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am trying to modify an app to add additional features. I have a function that looks like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_SELECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
    public static final String TAG = "nRFUART";
    private static final String TAG1 = "smsTAG";
    private static final int UART_PROFILE_CONNECTED = 20;
    private static final int UART_PROFILE_DISCONNECTED = 21;
    public static String content = null;
    private int mState = UART_PROFILE_DISCONNECTED;
    private UartService mService = null;
    private BluetoothDevice mDevice = null;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = null;
    private ListView messageListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    public Button btnConnectDisconnect,btnSend;
    private EditText edtMessage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBtAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{

            btnConnectDisconnect=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select);
            btnSend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
            edtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendText);
            mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            messageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessage);
            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message_detail);
            messageListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            messageListView.setDivider(null);
            //Call receiveBroadCast like this
            receiveBroadCast(getIntent().getStringExtra("message"));
            service_init();
        }

    ...

        // Handle Send button
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendText);
//              String message = editText.getText().toString();
                String message = content;
                byte[] value;
                try {
                    //send data to service
                    value = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    mService.writeRXCharacteristic(value);
                    //Update the log with time stamp
                    String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                    listAdapter.add("["+currentDateTimeString+"] TX: "+ message);
                    messageListView.smoothScrollToPosition(listAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                    edtMessage.setText("");
                    Log.i(TAG1, "success, value: " + value + " message: " + message);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i(TAG1, "fail" + e.toString());
                }
            }
        });

        ...

    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void receiveBroadCast(String text) {
        btnSend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        Log.i(TAG1, "test " + text);
        try {
            Log.i(TAG1, "success " + text);
            content = text;
            btnSend.performClick();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG1, "fail " + e.toString());
        }
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

But when I run the code I am getting the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the main.xml file that contains my button

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="Send" />
```

Any idea what is causing this error?

I am trying to make my receiveBroadcast automatically click on the sendButton everytime I supply a string to my receiveBroadcast.

This is my SMSReceiver class that I am using to call receiveBroadcast:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            if (bundle != null){
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                        Log.i(TAG, " success " + msgBody);
                        MainActivity Text = new MainActivity();
                        Text.receiveBroadCast(msgBody);
                        Intent intentsms = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        intentsms.putExtra("message", msgBody);
                        context.startActivity(intentsms);
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: Just from that Exception message, I would guess that you're directly instantiating an `Activity` class yourself; e.g., something like `MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();`. If so, you cannot do that, but we can't really provide any specific suggestions without more information.

Comment: Where are you calling `receiveBroadCast()`?

Comment: in a receiver class that I have created

Comment: And are you directly instantiating `MainActivity` in that Receiver, like I showed above?

Comment: yes i have initialised it as "MainActivity Text"

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that. An `Activity` must be instantiated by the system. You need some other mechanism to send data from the Receiver to the `Activity`. There are several options. You could send it on an `Intent` with `startActivity()`, like is shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6857648). Or you could use `LocalBroadcastManager`, like is shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26612814). Similar to that is using an event bus, which is mentioned in that answer, and demonstrated in [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38954540).

Comment: Of course, there are other ways, too, but the main point is that you need to somehow pass that data to a valid `Activity` instance, not one you create yourself.

Comment: So I past the data from my SmsReceiver to my onCreate using activities? Then receive the data in the activity in onCreate?

Comment: That's one possibility. To be honest, I prefer `LocalBroadcastManager` for this. It's in the support library, so it's an "official" component. It uses the native `Intent` and `BroadcastReceiver` classes that are already in the framework, so it's a very lightweight addition to your app. Additionally, its `sendBroadcast()` method returns a `boolean` to indicate if any Receiver's handle the broadcast, so you can do something else – e.g., showing a `Notification` instead – if your `MainActivity` doesn't happen to be running when a message comes in. I'll see if I can find a better example of that.

Comment: @VicTim kindly check the updated answer to get an idea

Comment: Here, this one is a little better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292. In that example, `ReceiverActivity` is your `MainActivity`, and `SenderActivity` is your SMS Receiver. The code in the `sendMessage()` method there is what you would use from the SMS Receiver's `onReceive()` to send `msgBody`. In `ReceiverActivity`, the `mMessageReceiver` will get that broadcast with `msgBody` (if it's active), and from its `onReceive()`, you can call your `receiveBroadCast()` method with the message retrieved from the `Intent`. Follow all of that?

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but base on my current code here, I believe the error lies in the     
public void receiveBroadCast(String text) {
        btnSend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
I am not sure why is it the findViewById is a null

Comment: Try debugging your app and you will know in which line exactly is your app crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For that thing to work for you. You will have to send the 
>   LocalBroadCastManager to MainActivity and there you will have to get
>   that data to perform your Action.

**Check the implementation below:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_SELECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
    public static final String TAG = "nRFUART";
    private static final String TAG1 = "smsTAG";
    private static final int UART_PROFILE_CONNECTED = 20;
    private static final int UART_PROFILE_DISCONNECTED = 21;
    public static String content = null;
    private int mState = UART_PROFILE_DISCONNECTED;
    private UartService mService = null;
    private BluetoothDevice mDevice = null;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = null;
    private ListView messageListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    public Button btnConnectDisconnect,btnSend;
    private EditText edtMessage;


    private BroadcastReceiver myMessageRec = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
            receiveBroadCast(message);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).registerReceiver(myMessageRec,
                new IntentFilter("myMessage"));
        btnConnectDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        edtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendText);
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        messageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessage);
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message_detail);
        messageListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        messageListView.setDivider(null);
        service_init();

        // Handle Send button
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendText);
//              String message = editText.getText().toString();
                String message = content;
                byte[] value;
                try {
                    //send data to service
                    value = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    mService.writeRXCharacteristic(value);
                    //Update the log with time stamp
                    String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                    listAdapter.add("[" + currentDateTimeString + "] TX: " + message);
                    messageListView.smoothScrollToPosition(listAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                    edtMessage.setText("");
                    Log.i(TAG1, "success, value: " + value + " message: " + message);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i(TAG1, "fail" + e.toString());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void receiveBroadCast(String text) {
        Log.i(TAG1, "test " + text);
        try {
            Log.i(TAG1, "success " + text);
            content = text;
            btnSend.performClick();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG1, "fail " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(myMessageRec);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

> SmsReceiver will look like this:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
                String str = "";
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        str += " :";
                        str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                        str += "\n";
                    }
                }
                Intent intentsms = new Intent("myMessage");
                intentsms.putExtra("message", str);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intentsms);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whenever I receive an SMS, the app restarts

Comment: That is because of this check `if (mBtAdapter == null)` so to fix that remove `finish;` and `return;` form the code as in updated answer.
And check why `mBtAdapter ` is null

Comment: I have updated my code to match what you have, but nothing is working, please advice if I made any mistakes along the way, thank you

Comment: Are you getting the `Toast` message "Bluetooth is not available" ?

Comment: nope, infact i am receiving the success logs from receive broadcast, but nothing is happening

Comment: that means `receiveBroadCast` is successully being called without NullPointerException so now what you want next ?

Comment: Just tested, I'm still getting the same error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: change your `SmsReceiver` class as updated in answer and then let me know

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but base on my current code here, I believe the error lies in the public void receiveBroadCast(String text) { btnSend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton); I am not sure why is it the findViewById is a null

Comment: above in my code i have put this `btnSend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);` line in `onCreate` so you need to remove this line from `receiveBroadCast`

Comment: @VicTim for now update onCreate() as updated in answer

Comment: I have deleted the btnSend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton) from my receiveBroadcast and followed your onCreate(), the app is reopening again on top of the current app

Comment: why do you have a curly bracket after serviec_init(), it seems to be causing me some syntax error

Comment: your code is closing my onCreate, putting btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  outside of the onCreate

Comment: I can't put receiveBroadCast inside onCreate, cannot resolve symbol 'text'

Comment: `receiveBroadCast` will be outside of `onCreate()` in MainActivity